# SQL Merge 2 Colums with the Same Name and data type, but are results of Sum Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this select statement. I know I can fix this with a Union but I have been told is not efficient and my bosses asked me to do it in a single query instead of Using Union because its the same table. And it makes sense.

```
 select 
 'No Photos' as 'Type',
  SUM( case when Cntimagedata  < 12 or cntimagedata is null  then 1 else 0 end) as     Value,
 'Incomplete Photos' as 'Type',
  SUM( case when Cntimagedata < 12 then 1 else 0 end) as Value
  from tablemain
```

The query generates the Following Table.

---

'Type' |   'Value'   |   'Type'  |   'Value'

No Photo  |   15 |    Incomplete Photos |   3

---

But my answer needs to be

---

'Type' -----------------|---- 'Value'

No Photo  ------------     |   15

Incomplete Photos -|   3

---

Having just 2 Columns instead of 4... is this possible? I have been trying to get this solution to work. And joins dont fit in this (I think), because its all the data I need is in this single table.

I can't use Union as I mention before because my bosses say I am making the query slower with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'No Photos' as 'Type', SUM( case when Cntimagedata  < 12 or cntimagedata is null  then 1 else 0 end) as     Value
FROM tablemain
UNION SELECT 'Incomplete Photos' as 'Type', SUM( case when Cntimagedata < 12 then 1 else 0 end) as Value
FROM  tablemain
```

Or since you can now put conditions in where clause

```
SELECT 'No Photos' as 'Type', count(cntimagedata) Value
FROM tablemain where Cntimagedata  < 12 or cntimagedata is null
UNION SELECT 'Incomplete Photos' as 'Type', count(cntimagedata) Value
FROM  tablemain where Cntimagedata  < 12
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @vittore, but I can't use Union as it slows down my query and my superiors want me to solve it with any other way because of that.

Comment: Slowdown most likely mean that you are not using proper indexing.

Comment: The data is being indexed by a Unique key. is there any other way I can index it? so you are saying Union doesn't necessarily is a slowdown in performance? I know its doesn't slow like a Cursor.

Comment: If you had index on the Cntimagedata field this union would run using two index scans.

Comment: cntimagedata doesn't have index, so it does mean it would have a slow performance right? Is there a way to debug this, Besides just calculating the time of execution?

Comment: Analyse estimated execution plan - that is words you are looking for. Just open MSSMS enter both queries and press `Display Estimated Execution Plan` button.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will check this out. To give actual fact of how union is affecting performance or not.

Comment: Wow you are right. The aggregate functions the concatenations, I suppose the Union is considered concatenation, it takes no time at all to complete. So its not a performance problem. Union its the actual solution for this problem.